# how to add objects to array of objects in class, from outside of the class in Java

Tags: java, arrays, class

I have the following code:

```
class Person{
   private Car [] cars;

   public Person(){
     //other variables...
     cars = new Car[10];
   }
   //other methods.....
   //...
   //...
   public void setCar(Car car, int position){
      this.cars[position] = car;
   }

   public Car getCar(int position){
      return cars[position];
   }
}
```

My `Car` class has no issues, the issue I have is when I assign a new `Car` to the array.

This is how I'm assigning it:

```
public class MainClass{
   public static void main(String [] args){
      Car newCar = new Car();
      Person newPerson = new Person();
      int position = 0;
      int x= 0;
      int option;

      do{
        //Code for menu options and user input detection of options...
        //...
        //...
        switch(option){
          case 1:
           // get user input and set it to newCar variables.....
           newCar.setVariableX();
           newCar.setVariableY();

           //assigment of new car to array of cars in newPerson
           newPerson.setCar(newCar,position);
           position++;
          break;

          case 2: x =2; //exit option
          break;

      }while(x!=2);

      // invoque print option for Array of Cars
   }
}
```

So the assignment to the array appears to be correct and prints out ok with only **ONE** `Car` added, but if I add **MORE** than one `car`, it assigns the new `car` variables to all the positions of the array. For example:

```
Add car1 to cars[position].
position++
Add car2 to cars[position].
```

and the result I get is

```
cars[0] = car2;
cars[1] = car2;
```

**Found the issue** thanks guys:

```
      public class MainClass{
        public static void main(String [] args){
           Car newCar;   //<-----------changed this
           Person newPerson = new Person();
           int position = 0;
           int x= 0;
           int option;

      do{
        //Code for menu options and user input detection of options...
        //...
        //...
        switch(option){
          case 1:
             newCar = new Car(); //<------------This fixed the issue
           // get user input and set it to newCar variables.....
           newCar.setVariableX();
           newCar.setVariableY();

           //assigment of new car to array of cars in newPerson
           newPerson.setCar(newCar,position);
           position++;
          break;

          case 2: x =2; //exit option
          break;

      }while(x!=2);

      // invoque print option for Array of Cars
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how it could cause the problem you're seeing, but I notice you don't end your `case`s with a `break`. That's going to cause you some trouble.

Comment: yes i do have breaks in my code, just forgot to add them here on my post.

Comment: You are always adding the same car

Comment: how do you add new car you need a new statement each time you add a car. Your code is not complete

Comment: I don't think that's the problem @JawadLeWywadi. He wants an array of references to the same object, but he should have an array of those references nonetheless.

Comment: If he is always adding the same reference he will always have the same objects in the array. So it is important to know how does he creates his car instances. @ErikMacias please show how you creates does objects.

Comment: Post a minimal but **complete** example reproducing the problem.

Comment: Yes, but he would still have a full array of those references. As long as the incrementation counter is not touched, it should be fine.

Comment: Thats what he gets I assume. Anyways question is not complete. So who knows.

Comment: the example is at the end.  Add car1 to cars[position].
position++
Add car2 to cars[position]. , the reult is when i print the array: cars[0] = car2;
cars[1] = car2;

Comment: How you create your car1 and car2??

Comment: Can you please just post your code? The scope for your loop is wrong, and you place parenthesis right after you declare your class as though it's a method. We might not even be able to see what the problem is.

Comment: When user chooses option 1 on menu, witch is the switch option 1, it assigns new variables to Car newCar.

Comment: @ErikMacias code please we understand what you want. But you should show how you do it.

Comment: Can you not use ArrayList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have this:

```
newCar = new Car();
newCar.setVariableX();
newCar.setVariableY();
```

Your are always adding the same reference so when you modify the object all the objects in your array are modified.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `Car newCar = new Car()` statement *inside* your `do while` loop and it should work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ArrayList to store multiple objects and add / remove when needed. This way you're not limited to 10 cars.

```
class Person{
   private ArrayList<Car> cars;

   public Person(){
     cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
   }
   //other methods.....
   //...
   //...
   public void setCar(Car car, int position){
      this.cars[position] = car;
   }

   public Car getCar(int position){
      return cars[position];
   }

   public void addCar(Car car){
      cars.add(car);
   }
}
```

Also your current problem is that you keep adding the same Car object as newCar never gets re-assigned.

Comment: Can you access an ArrayList with square brackets?